# How Multithreading work in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have some confusion regarding Multithreading in java.

Let say I have 3 CPU having following details

CPU 1  :  Having 2 Core
CPU 2  :  Having 2 Core
CPU 3  :  Having 1 Core

So I have  3 CPU with the 5 Core in it.

Now I want to execute the 5 thread.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Thread threadA = new CounterThread();
Thread threadB = new CounterThread();
Thread threadC = new CounterThread();
Thread threadD = new CounterThread();
Thread threadE = new CounterThread();

threadA.start();
threadB.start();
threadC.start();
threadD.start();
threadE.start();
}
```

So once that main program get executed. will it run on all different 5 Core ??

if it is yes then who is handling to pass the request to different core and how ?

Could someone please elaborate on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "_So once that main program get executed. will it run on all different 5 Core_". First, you have **6** threads. Second, there are no guarantees about how the OS decides to schedule your threads.

Comment: The free Oracle JVM only runs on a single CPU.  If you want to use multiple cpu's it is essentially hard.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: but the Oracle JVM's threads are native threads, and so the OS can and will use multiple cores if it feels it should.

Comment: @Boris thanks ..yes i forgot for main..... is all scheduling decided by OS not JVM ??

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels yes.  But we are talking three different CPU's here.  Either this is a three-CPU server or three machines each with its own CPU.   As the CPU's are not identical I find the single server unlikely.

Comment: @RaviB Java has had "native threads" for very long and it is the operating system that schedules those.  You may be thinking of green threads which to the best of my knowledge is not supported by modern versions of Oracle Java.

Comment: Not thinking of any thread just wanted to understand how the OS will do the job in my case.. and it is not gaurnttee to run on mulitiple core then what the point to make multiple core for threading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So once that main program get executed. will it run on all different 5 Core ??

It is possible, but there is no way in pure Java to control this. If the thread block they could all run on the same core.

> if it is yes then who is handling to pass the request to different core and how ?

There is no concept of a request at the hardware level, all you have is memory which need to updated in a thread safe manner. This allows you to build data structure like thread safe queue which you can pass messages which contain a request.

> is all scheduling decided by OS not JVM

If you have native threads, the OS does everything. The JVM makes the right systems calls to make it happen.

Comment: R u saying , So as  a programmer, I don't have any control and I will also not able to see on which core the thread is going on ??

Comment: @RaviB you can control it and see which core a thread is on using a library (I have one https://github.com/OpenHFT/Java-Thread-Affinity) but this is rarely very useful. In general, you should let the scheduler do it's job.  Just as you don't control which memory bank your data is stored, or where on your disk, a file is stored.

Comment: Sorry for little bit confusion just bring me out of this confusion that ... OS will decide where to execute the thread & if it is not gaurtee that the thread will execute on single core or on different core .. Then what the point to make the multiple core.... ??

Comment: @RaviB It will use multiple cores when you really have two threads running at the same time. Note: when you split a program across multiple sockets or NUMA regions it can run much slower, so the OS tended to keep a process on one socket or NUMA region when it can.

Comment: @RaviB say you have 5 threads that don't run for long, they might all start and die on the same CPU your main thread ran on. If you have five blocking threads e.g. IO, you might still all run on the same CPU.  If you have 5 CPU intensive threads running for a while at the same time, they might all end up on different CPUs. (Note some cores have more than one logical CPU)

Comment: @ Peter Lawrey Thanks you so much that I wanted to know.